# Implementing a force update for IOS App based on a min version criteria

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing an IOS Application. I have a use case in which we have to force users to necessarily upgrade. For example the user might be on version 1 and two more versions 2 and 3(which exists on app store currently). Now we determined that version 1 has a security vulnerability so we open an alert which asks for user to upgrade via app store. My approach right now is the follows:-

```
1. Implement a rest service which vends the minimum required version. 
2. Implement a local upgrade handler that calls the rest service, 
   gets the current version(natively) and compares the version 
   against the min required version. 
3. If the version is lower than min required version, upgrade by   
   opening app store.
```

So far I have been able to successfully implement the rest service and part of the upgrade handler. My alert view code looks as the following:-

```
private func alertUserWithHandler(title: String?, message: String, upgradeHandler: ((UIAlertAction) -> Void)? ){
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: upgradeHandler))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
}
```

And my upgrade handler looks as the follows:-

```
// The upgrade handler takes the user to the AppStore.
func upgradeHandler(action:UIAlertAction) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:"location in appstore"))
}
```

The problem with this approach is its not a blocking handler. The user might press Ok button and then go to app store and then come back to resume using the app. We want to force an upgrade (i.e the user cannot use the app until the upgrade is sucessfully completed).

Can anyone suggest a good way to force user upgrades?

Comment: You could present another AlertController in `upgradeHandler()` that has no buttons.

Comment: @FelixSFD - Ok but how else would I pass a handler?

Comment: You could send an app version with user verification request at app start. So on the back end it would return an error if the version is too old. In the app you would nee to handle this error separately.

Comment: @MaksTheAwesome - This operation would be per request? Its not a bad idea, but its unnecessary overhead if the check can be done once.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. My point was to check it once when you start application and check if the api token is still valid.

Answer (score 1):

I created a sharedInstance() in a Singleton class that hits a web service with version and build as parameters. If it comes back true, I present a view modally over the app that cannot be dismissed until that web service comes back false. By putting it into a sharedInstance I don't have to call it on every view controller. I also call it once when the app launches initially as well.